# Cannot boot Windows after removing reserved partition and resizing installation partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, partitioning

I removed Windows 10 x64 (1809)'s 16MB reserved partition located just before the installation partition (which I then resized to be 84MB smaller, with the 84MB unallocated space at the beginning) and increased the SSD's EFI partition, which was located just before the reserved partition, by 100MB (by adding these 16MB+64MB).

I also kind of destroyed the EFI folder on the EFI partiton by accidentally replacing the entirety of its contents with other ones (I actually wanted to add the latter, not replace existing ones), so I no longer have the Windows bootloader.

I installed Ubuntu after all this happened and, sadly, not even GRUB sees my Windows installation..

I'd really appreciate some hints on how to regain access to my Windows installation.

**Some things I tried so far** (I ran them from a Windows 8.1 Installation DVD, since I didn't seem to have a working Windows 10 DVD):

1. The commands

bootrec /ScanOs

bootrec /RebuildBcd

Both detected `0` Windows installations.

2. The command `bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s x: /f ALL` gave me the error 'Failure when attempting to copy boot files.'

EDIT: I also posted the question on these websites, but have not received an answer yet:
https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/125036-cant-boot-windows-10-after-messing-reserved-installation-partitions.html#post1552350

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/cant-boot-windows-10-after-messing-reserved/97e24d17-fcdf-467e-a6b0-7b978542b40f?tm=1547133877303

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find any other solutions, I decided to back up my data on the Windows partition and reinstall.

Answer (score -2):

If I were you I would create a Windows 10 bootable USB using the media creation tool and use the tool to format your hard drive and reinstall everything. In the setup you can access cmd by pressing shift + F10 and then you can access DISKPART.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Formatting my entire drive is the last option I'd like to try (EDIT: because it's a bit difficult for me to save all the data and it takes quite a lot of time to reinstall everything). It's good to know the console can also be brough up with SHIFT+F10 (it can also be done by choosing 'Repair your computer' -> Advanced Options -> Command Prompt)

Comment: Starting over from scratch is always an option, but it's destructive and involves a lot of work.  Can you add a little explanation as to why you recommend this extreme solution at this point?